# codeigniter alias rows does not work on hosting

Tags: sql, codeigniter

i typo sql alias in codeigniter, it works well on localhost but it give error on hosting why??

```
    <?php   

 $sonuc = $this->db->query("SELECT t.id, t.cins_id, t.resim, t.saatlik_uretim, ut.uretimmiktar,  ut.mySUM, tk.cins FROM tavuklar t 
 INNER JOIN tavukkat tk ON tk.id = t.cins_id 
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT tavuk_id, uretimmiktar, COUNT(*), SUM(uretimmiktar) AS mySUM from uretimtavuk WHERE user_id = ".$info->id." AND durum=0  GROUP BY tavuk_id )ut ON ut.tavuk_id = t.cins_id ORDER BY t.id DESC");

   foreach($sonuc->result_array() as $bilgi){
echo  $bilgi["mySUM"];

}
?>
```

how i can get alias name on hosting??

i get this error;

```
unknow undefined index : mySUM 
Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on boolean
```

Comment: error on hosting? what is the error from your hosting server? did you check your database/table/column, index etc.. structure is identical on localhost and production?

Comment: unknow indefined index : mySUM

Fatal error: Call to a member function result_array() on boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your hosting db probably lowercase or uppercase the return data from query database

try this

```
echo  $bilgi["mysum"];
```

or this

```
echo  $bilgi["MYSUM"];
```